# Python test given path to file in given path of folder

Tags: python, path, filenames

User input two strings, one is `filename` and the other one is `folder`. The `filename` variable is a path to some file on disk. And the `folder` variable is a path to some folder on disk. I want to know if the file is located *in* the folder (either directly or in its sub folders).

For example:

```py
isContains("C:\\a.txt", "C:\\") # True
isContains("C:\\a.txt", "C:\\a") # False
isContains("C:\\a.txt", "D:\\") # False
isContains("C:\\a\\b\\c\\d.txt", "C:\\") # True
isContains("C:\\a\\b\\c\\d.txt", "C:\\a\\b") # True
```

What I have done yet:

```py
import os
isContains = lambda filename, folder: os.path.abspath(filename).startswith(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(folder), ''))
```

But I believe there must be some more elegant ways I didn't find out. As these code looks too complex. How should I implement this function?

---

My program is running on Windows. But I want the code be platform independent.

Comment: It's already implemented in `pathlib`: [`Path.is_relative_to()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.is_relative_to). You can just do `Path(filename).is_relative_to(folder)`. Alternatively you can use [`os.path.commonprefix()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.commonprefix) and check for non-empty return: `commonprefix((filename, folder))`

Comment: @OlvinRoght But `os.path.commonprefix(('c:\\a\\b\\c\\d.txt', 'c:\\a\\d'))` is not empty (should be false)

Comment: Exactly, I've not thought about all possible cases writing first comment. Option with `commonprefix()` requires additional return validation to meet all conditions, so if you don't want additional *(unnecessary)* headache - use `pathlib`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have no strict requirement to use [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html), I'd recommend for all path-related work use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), it will save you lot of time.

There's special method of [`Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path)*([`PurePath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath))* class which does exactly what you're trying to implement - [`Path.is_relative_to()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.is_relative_to). Basically, you just need to initialize `Path` from your `filename` and call this method with `folder`:

```py
Path(filename).is_relative_to(folder)
```